# using boto3 to get file list and download files

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I was given this s3 url: s3://file.share.external.bdex.com/Offrs

In this url is a battery of files I need to download.

I have this code:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                      aws_access_key_id='<<ACCESS KEY>>',
                      aws_secret_access_key='<<SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>>'
                      )
object_listing = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='file.share.external.bdex.com/Offrs',
                                    Prefix='')

print(object_listing)
```

I have tried:

```
Bucket='file.share.external.bdex.com', Prefix='Offrs'
Bucket='s3://file.share.external.bdex.com/Offrs/'
Bucket='file.share.external.bdx.com/Offrs', Prefix='Offrs'
```

and several other configurations, all saying I'm not following the regex. due to the slash, or not found.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bucket = 'file.share.external.bdx.com'
Prefix = 'Offrs/'
```

You can test your access permissions via the AWS CLI:

```
aws s3 ls s3://file.share.external.bdex.com/Offrs/
```

Comment: If the above does not solve your issue, please Edit your question to show the code that you used and the **exact error message**.